# How many ways you can go from point A to point B

Tags: visual

[image]

I know I have drawn the picture badly but can you tell how many ways we can go from point A to point B.

each path used once and no turning back...

Comment: Infinite.$\phantom{!}$

Comment: Can the same point be visited more than once? Or each path used just once?

Comment: @WeatherVane each path used once and there is no turning back...

Comment: Well, this is classic combination math question :P

Comment: @Conifers To be fair, counting paths on triangular grids can be a [research-level mathematics problem](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-319-26145-4_9).

Answer (score 7):

My answer is below

> > Ans: 321 
> >  because there is only one way of getting to each of the points in a northerly direction, and also going direct
> >  east 
> >   [image]

Answer (score 3):

Assuming we can go only right and/or up, my answer is (as [@SayedMohdAli](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/89069/51581)'s answer)

> **321**

which was produced by this C code

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MINGRID 2
#define MAXGRID 7

int grid;
int paths;

void recur(int x, int y)
{
    if(x == grid - 1 && y == grid - 1) {
        paths++;
    }
    else if(x < grid && y < grid) {
        recur(x + 1, y);
        recur(x, y + 1);
        recur(x + 1, y + 1);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    for(grid = MINGRID; grid <= MAXGRID; grid++) {
        paths = 0;
        recur(0, 0);
        printf(">! grid=%d paths=%d  \n", grid, paths);
    }
}
```

along with solutions for other sized grids:

> grid=2 paths=3
>  grid=3 paths=13
>  grid=4 paths=63
>  grid=5 paths=321
>  grid=6 paths=1683
>  grid=7 paths=8989

and OEIS has this sequence [A001850](https://oeis.org/A001850).

> Central Delannoy numbers
>  3,13,63,321,1683,8989
>  Number of paths from (0,0) to (n,n) in an n X n grid using only steps north, northeast and east (i.e., steps (1,0), (1,1), and (0,1))

although I didn't look it up first!
There doesn't seem to be a clear and simple formula for it.

Comment: +1 for OEIS has this sequence Central Delannoy numbers

Answer (score 0):

In a crude mathematical induction applied, I can

> move in 3 ways, if there is one square, 31( 9{diagonally} + 11{lateral)} + 11{lateral}) ways, if there are 4 squares ... and so on...

And hence with

> 16 squares, it is 2^17 - 1 ways